# JBoss AS 7.2 - deploy exception: Unable to start JGroups

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, infinispan, jgroups

We are running our JEE6 app on JBoss AS 7.2 with mod_cluster as a load balancer and S3_Ping, all on separate EC2 instances, the jboss instances are running with the standalone_full_ha config

About a week ago I upgraded our ec2 instance types from c3.large to c4.large, at the same time I also updated the JDK from Java 1.6 to 1.7, our application is running fine after the migration however I have run into an issue where (roughly 1 in 5) JBoss instances fail to deploy the application when a new instance is created (full stack trace below). I have found that usually I can restart JBoss and a second redeploy works ok however in some cases I have to terminate the ec2 instance and launch a new one.

During the migration I copied the entire JBoss directory across so the JBoss installation has remained the same, the only change is the Java version and a newer version of Amazon Linux

New Java Version:

```
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.7.2.68.amzn1-x86_64 u111-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

I assume that due to the intermittent nature that this could be a timing issue, I have included the startup script we use to startup a new instance:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "-------Running Instance Startup Script--------"
echo "Downloading Ear Archive"
aws s3 cp s3://processor-ear/production/Processor.ear /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear --region eu-west-1
if [ ! -f /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear ]; then
    echo "Error - Processor.ear was not downloaded!"
    exit 0
fi
echo "Archive download success"
echo "Downloading server config file"
aws s3 cp s3://processor-ear/production/standalone-full-ha.xml /home/ec2-user/standalone-full-ha.xml --region eu-west-1
if [ ! -f /home/ec2-user/standalone-full-ha.xml ]; then
    echo "Error - standalone-full-ha.xml was not downloaded!"
    exit 0
fi
echo "Server config download success"
chown ec2-user /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear
chgrp ec2-user /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear
chown jboss /home/ec2-user/standalone-full-ha.xml
chgrp jboss /home/ec2-user/standalone-full-ha.xml
cp /home/ec2-user/standalone-full-ha.xml /opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone-full-ha.xml
echo "Deploying Archive"
bash /opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect commands="deploy /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear"
echo "Checking deployment status..."
DEPLOYMENT_STATUS=$(bash /opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c --commands="cd deployment,cd Processor.ear, read-attribute status")
echo $DEPLOYMENT_STATUS
if [ '$DEPLOYMENT_STATUS' != 'OK' ]; then
    service jboss restart
    sleep 5
    bash /opt/jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect commands="deploy /home/ec2-user/Processor.ear"
fi
```

As you can see I have included a hack at the end to attempt a second redeploy if the first fails

Here is the exception in the jboss logs...

```
Oct 06 06:56:30,649 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
Oct 06 06:56:30,650 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
Oct 06 06:56:30,698 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.ejb.repl: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.ejb.repl: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:87) [jboss-as-clustering-common-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final.jar:2.1.0.Final]
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:247)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:678)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:649)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:545)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:559)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheService.start(CacheService.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:82) [jboss-as-clustering-common-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:886)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:657)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:646)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:549)
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:225)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:209)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:203)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.start(TP.java:1065)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TCP.start(TCP.java:83)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:948)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:827)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:525)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:277)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:268)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:207)
    ... 23 more

Oct 06 06:56:30,702 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.singleton.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.singleton.default: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:87) [jboss-as-clustering-common-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.0.Final.jar:2.1.0.Final]
Caused by: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:247)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:678)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:649)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:545)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:559)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheService.start(CacheService.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:82) [jboss-as-clustering-common-7.2.0.Final.jar:7.2.0.Final]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:886)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:657)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:646)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:549)
    at org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry.start(GlobalComponentRegistry.java:225)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:209)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:203)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.start(TP.java:1065)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TCP.start(TCP.java:83)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:948)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:827)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:525)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:277)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:268)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:207)
    ... 23 more

Oct 06 06:56:30,702 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.3.Final
Oct 06 06:56:30,805 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.TransactionManagerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000161: Using a batchMode transaction manager
Oct 06 06:56:30,832 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
Oct 06 06:56:30,833 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.infinispan.ejb.remote-connector-client-mappings: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.infinispan.ejb.remote-connector-client-mappings: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:87)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to invoke method public void org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start() on object of type JGroupsTransport
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:205)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:886)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:657)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:226)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:158)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:296)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.getOrCreateComponent(ComponentRegistry.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeInjectionMethod(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:246)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.access$000(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:86)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$Component.injectDependencies(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:814)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:220)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.registerComponentInternal(ComponentRegistry.java:188)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.registerComponent(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:175)
    at org.infinispan.factories.InternalCacheFactory.bootstrap(InternalCacheFactory.java:101)
    at org.infinispan.factories.InternalCacheFactory.createAndWire(InternalCacheFactory.java:80)
    at org.infinispan.factories.InternalCacheFactory.createCache(InternalCacheFactory.java:64)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:682)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:649)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:545)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:559)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.getCache(DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager.java:100)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheService.start(CacheService.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.msc.AsynchronousService$1.run(AsynchronousService.java:82)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.CacheException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:209)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.infinispan.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:203)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:891) [rt.jar:1.7.0_111]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.start(TP.java:1065)
    at org.jgroups.protocols.TCP.start(TCP.java:83)
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:948)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:827)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:525)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:277)
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:268)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.startJGroupsChannelIfNeeded(JGroupsTransport.java:207)
    ... 97 more
```

Any JGroups / JBoss guys out there seen this before? Can provide more config details if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so the issue is that probe handlers are registered in a non thread-safe linked list. This was fixed in 3.2.12 (see [1]).

So either upgrade to JGroups 3.2.12 or try setting `enable_diagnostics` to false. 3.2.12 should be compatible with 3.2.7, although I don't know if this has been tested.

[1] https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JGRP-1869

Comment: many thanks, I have just successfully deployed with jgroups 3.2.12 so it seems to be compatible, I will run for a few days and see how it goes